# Distribute quantity through min max in Excel

Tags: excel

I initially tried to do this directly in SQL Server but it seems like it can't be possible through query so I want to calculate this "Distribute" column in Excel. Below is the details of the question. Appreciate if someone can help here.

I have following column in Excel and want to calculate values in "Distribute" column.

| Item | Qty | Customer | Rank | Min | Max | Distribute |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1500 | 0101 | 1 | 250 | 600 | ???? |
| 001 | 1500 | 0104 | 2 | 0 | 500 | ???? |
| 001 | 1500 | 0103 | 3 | 100 | 300 | ???? |
| 001 | 1500 | 0105 | 4 | 200 | 300 | ???? |
| 002 | 2000 | 0104 | 1 | 200 | 600 | ???? |
| 002 | 2000 | 0105 | 2 | 150 | 700 | ???? |
| 002 | 2000 | 0101 | 3 | 100 | 200 | ???? |
| 002 | 2000 | 0103 | 4 | 100 | 500 | ???? |
| 002 | 2000 | 0102 | 5 | 50 | 200 | ???? |
| 003 | 800 | 0103 | 1 | 100 | 500 | ???? |
| 003 | 800 | 0102 | 2 | 50 | 200 | ???? |
| 003 | 800 | 0101 | 2 | 50 | 100 | ???? |
| 003 | 800 | 0104 | 3 | 50 | 80 | ???? |

There are multiple items (Item) and each item has fixed quantity available (Qty)

Each item is distributed in different customers (Customers) based on their rank (Rank). The ranks are group by for every item. Data is already sorted via Rank column for every item. Multiple customers against an item can have same rank.

From the total quantity (Qty) of each item, every customer must get minimum quantity mentioned in (Min) column irrespective of its rank.

The remaining quantity of every item must be distribute based on the rank of the customer making sure that it should not exceed to the maximum quantity mentioned in (Max) column.

It is OK, if total quantity of the item is not consumed after distribution maximum quantity to all customer.

What I am after is the result something like this:

| Item | Qty | Customer | Rank | Min | Max | Distribute |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 1500 | 0101 | 1 | 250 | 600 | 600 |
| 001 | 1500 | 0104 | 2 | 0 | 500 | 500 |
| 001 | 1500 | 0103 | 3 | 100 | 300 | 200 |
| 001 | 1500 | 0105 | 4 | 200 | 300 | 200 |
| 002 | 2000 | 0104 | 1 | 200 | 600 | 600 |
| 002 | 2000 | 0105 | 2 | 150 | 700 | 700 |
| 002 | 2000 | 0101 | 3 | 100 | 200 | 200 |
| 002 | 2000 | 0103 | 4 | 100 | 500 | 450 |
| 002 | 2000 | 0102 | 5 | 50 | 200 | 50 |
| 003 | 800 | 0103 | 1 | 100 | 500 | 500 |
| 003 | 800 | 0102 | 2 | 50 | 200 | 200 |
| 003 | 800 | 0101 | 2 | 50 | 100 | 50 |
| 003 | 800 | 0104 | 3 | 50 | 80 | 50 |

Looking forward if you can provide a formula or solution here. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please, post what manual formula you would use. If you know how to make the calculus on a paper, we gladly can help you to translate that into Excel formulas. If you are searching for a math solution because you have no idea of what to do, then I strongly suggest to post this question on https://stats.stackexchange.com/ because it fits better there.

Comment: A (sincle) formula is most likely going to be heavy (or very long and complicated). A VBA solution would be perhaps easier. Do you strictly need a formula? Can the solution include more than a cell for each result?

Comment: I don't mind a VBA solution... or creating more columns to reach to the required results

Comment: Why costumer 0101 gets 50 of item 003 while costumer 0102 gets 200? Is there a second order type or ranking? Do you prioritize those with higher maximum request?

Comment: This is based on ranking. a) All customers will get minimum quantity first. b) From the remaining quantity, customer with higher rank, will get maximum quantity first. 0101 gets 50 because after 500+200 (for customer 0103 and 0102) is 700 and there are only 100 items remaining out of which 0101 and 0104 will get minimum first i.e. 50 qty. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: But 0102 and 0101 have the same rank. Why 0102 gets his request fulfilled while 0101 gets only the minimum? Why is not the opposite? Why don't they have a "equal share" of the remaining?

Comment: Good point!... it should also follow the sequence.. since 0102 is above 0101 so it has the higher priority even through the rank is same for both.

Comment: Ok then we can assume that the table is already sorted by `Item` and `Rank` and will stay that way. I should have already a solution then. Will report it soon.

Comment: You say in your first line that you have tried this in SQL but you dont think it is possible, is it actually in SQL server that you would want an answer, or are you happy with the responses to cover excel

Comment: Ideally... I want the solution in SQL Server 2008.... but if we can get the solution in Excel... it work for me as well

Answer (score 0):

## FORMULA BASED SOLUTION

Here is a possible formula based solution with multiple cells involed that assumes the table is already properly sorted (by rank with any order then by rank from smaller to greater) and will stay that way:

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Item | Qty | Customer | Rank | Min | Max | [Cumulative] Qty - Min | Basic | [Cumulative] Remain | Extra | Distribute |
| 1 | 1500 | 101 | 1 | 250 | 600 | =MAX(0,IF(A1<>A2,B2-E2,G1-E2)) | =IF(A2<>A1,MIN(B2,E2),MIN(G1,E2)) | =IF(A1<>A2,AGGREGATE(15,6,G:G/(A:A=A2),1),MAX(0,I1-(F1-E1))) | =MIN(I2,F2-E2) | =H2+J2 |
| 1 | 1500 | 104 | 2 | 0 | 500 | =MAX(0,IF(A2<>A3,B3-E3,G2-E3)) | =IF(A3<>A2,MIN(B3,E3),MIN(G2,E3)) | =IF(A2<>A3,AGGREGATE(15,6,G:G/(A:A=A3),1),MAX(0,I2-(F2-E2))) | =MIN(I3,F3-E3) | =H3+J3 |
| 1 | 1500 | 103 | 3 | 100 | 300 | =MAX(0,IF(A3<>A4,B4-E4,G3-E4)) | =IF(A4<>A3,MIN(B4,E4),MIN(G3,E4)) | =IF(A3<>A4,AGGREGATE(15,6,G:G/(A:A=A4),1),MAX(0,I3-(F3-E3))) | =MIN(I4,F4-E4) | =H4+J4 |
| 1 | 1500 | 105 | 4 | 200 | 300 | =MAX(0,IF(A4<>A5,B5-E5,G4-E5)) | =IF(A5<>A4,MIN(B5,E5),MIN(G4,E5)) | =IF(A4<>A5,AGGREGATE(15,6,G:G/(A:A=A5),1),MAX(0,I4-(F4-E4))) | =MIN(I5,F5-E5) | =H5+J5 |
| 2 | 2000 | 104 | 1 | 200 | 600 | =MAX(0,IF(A5<>A6,B6-E6,G5-E6)) | =IF(A6<>A5,MIN(B6,E6),MIN(G5,E6)) | =IF(A5<>A6,AGGREGATE(15,6,G:G/(A:A=A6),1),MAX(0,I5-(F5-E5))) | =MIN(I6,F6-E6) | =H6+J6 |
| 2 | 2000 | 105 | 2 | 150 | 700 | =MAX(0,IF(A6<>A7,B7-E7,G6-E7)) | =IF(A7<>A6,MIN(B7,E7),MIN(G6,E7)) | =IF(A6<>A7,AGGREGATE(15,6,G:G/(A:A=A7),1),MAX(0,I6-(F6-E6))) | =MIN(I7,F7-E7) | =H7+J7 |
| 2 | 2000 | 101 | 3 | 100 | 200 | =MAX(0,IF(A7<>A8,B8-E8,G7-E8)) | =IF(A8<>A7,MIN(B8,E8),MIN(G7,E8)) | =IF(A7<>A8,AGGREGATE(15,6,G:G/(A:A=A8),1),MAX(0,I7-(F7-E7))) | =MIN(I8,F8-E8) | =H8+J8 |
| 2 | 2000 | 103 | 4 | 100 | 500 | =MAX(0,IF(A8<>A9,B9-E9,G8-E9)) | =IF(A9<>A8,MIN(B9,E9),MIN(G8,E9)) | =IF(A8<>A9,AGGREGATE(15,6,G:G/(A:A=A9),1),MAX(0,I8-(F8-E8))) | =MIN(I9,F9-E9) | =H9+J9 |
| 2 | 2000 | 102 | 5 | 50 | 200 | =MAX(0,IF(A9<>A10,B10-E10,G9-E10)) | =IF(A10<>A9,MIN(B10,E10),MIN(G9,E10)) | =IF(A9<>A10,AGGREGATE(15,6,G:G/(A:A=A10),1),MAX(0,I9-(F9-E9))) | =MIN(I10,F10-E10) | =H10+J10 |
| 3 | 800 | 103 | 1 | 100 | 500 | =MAX(0,IF(A10<>A11,B11-E11,G10-E11)) | =IF(A11<>A10,MIN(B11,E11),MIN(G10,E11)) | =IF(A10<>A11,AGGREGATE(15,6,G:G/(A:A=A11),1),MAX(0,I10-(F10-E10))) | =MIN(I11,F11-E11) | =H11+J11 |
| 3 | 800 | 102 | 2 | 50 | 200 | =MAX(0,IF(A11<>A12,B12-E12,G11-E12)) | =IF(A12<>A11,MIN(B12,E12),MIN(G11,E12)) | =IF(A11<>A12,AGGREGATE(15,6,G:G/(A:A=A12),1),MAX(0,I11-(F11-E11))) | =MIN(I12,F12-E12) | =H12+J12 |
| 3 | 800 | 101 | 2 | 50 | 100 | =MAX(0,IF(A12<>A13,B13-E13,G12-E13)) | =IF(A13<>A12,MIN(B13,E13),MIN(G12,E13)) | =IF(A12<>A13,AGGREGATE(15,6,G:G/(A:A=A13),1),MAX(0,I12-(F12-E12))) | =MIN(I13,F13-E13) | =H13+J13 |
| 3 | 800 | 104 | 3 | 50 | 80 | =MAX(0,IF(A13<>A14,B14-E14,G13-E14)) | =IF(A14<>A13,MIN(B14,E14),MIN(G13,E14)) | =IF(A13<>A14,AGGREGATE(15,6,G:G/(A:A=A14),1),MAX(0,I13-(F13-E13))) | =MIN(I14,F14-E14) | =H14+J14 |

## VBA SOLUTION

Here is a possible VBA solution that assumes the table is already properly sorted (by rank with any order then by rank from smaller to greater) and will stay that way:

```
Sub SubDistribution()
    
    Dim RngData As Range
    Dim RngItem As Range
    Dim RngQty As Range
    Dim RngMin As Range
    Dim RngMax As Range
    Dim RngDistribute As Range
    Dim VarArray() As Variant
    Dim DblItemCol As Double
    Dim DblQtyCol As Double
    Dim DblMinCol As Double
    Dim DblMaxCol As Double
    Dim DblRow As Double
    Dim DblCounter01 As Double
    Dim DblQuantity As Double
    Dim BlnFirstLap As Boolean
    
    
    Set RngData = Range("A2")
    Set RngQty = Range("B2")
    Set RngItem = Range("A2")
    Set RngMin = Range("E2")
    Set RngMax = Range("F2")
    Set RngDistribute = Range("G2")
    
    
    DblItemCol = RngData.Column - RngItem.Column + 1
    DblQtyCol = RngData.Column - RngQty.Column + 1
    DblMinCol = RngData.Column - RngMin.Column + 1
    DblMaxCol = RngData.Column - RngMax.Column + 1
    
    
    Set RngData = Range(RngData, RngData.End(xlToRight).End(xlDown))
    
    ReDim VarArray(1 To RngData.Rows.Count)
    
    For DblRow = 1 To RngData.Rows.Count
        If RngItem.Offset(DblRow).Value = RngItem.Offset(DblRow - 1).Value And BlnFirstLap = False Then
            DblQuantity = RngQty.Offset(DblRow - 1).Value
            BlnFirstLap = True
        Else
            If RngItem.Offset(DblRow).Value <> RngItem.Offset(DblRow - 1).Value Then
                BlnFirstLap = False
            End If
        End If
        
        
        If RngItem.Offset(DblRow).Value <> RngItem.Offset(DblRow - 1) Then
            VarArray(DblRow) = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Min(RngQty.Offset(DblRow - 1), RngMin.Offset(DblRow - 1))
        Else
            VarArray(DblRow) = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Min(DblQuantity, RngMin.Offset(DblRow - 1))
        End If
        DblQuantity = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Max(0, DblQuantity - RngMin.Offset(DblRow - 1).Value)
        
        If BlnFirstLap = True Then
            DblCounter01 = DblCounter01 + 1
        Else
            For DblCounter01 = DblCounter01 To 0 Step -1
                VarArray(DblRow - DblCounter01) = VarArray(DblRow - DblCounter01) + Excel.WorksheetFunction.Min(DblQuantity, RngMax.Offset(DblRow - 1 - DblCounter01) - RngMin.Offset(DblRow - 1 - DblCounter01))
                DblQuantity = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Max(0, DblQuantity - (RngMax.Offset(DblRow - 1 - DblCounter01).Value - RngMin.Offset(DblRow - 1 - DblCounter01).Value))
                
            Next
            
            DblCounter01 = 0
        End If
    Next
    
    RngDistribute.Resize(UBound(VarArray)).Value = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(VarArray)
    
End Sub
```

Comment: The formula is meant for cell G2. The formula checks if the current row has a item different from the previous row. In such case, the value from `Min` is subtracted from the value in the `Qty` (we take from the original quantity). Otherwise the value from `Min` is subtracted from the cell right above the one with the formula (therefore from the quantity minus all the quantity taken from this item original quantity so far). Anyway: i've realized now that the solution assume the quantity is always sufficient to satisfy the overall min request. I'm working on a edit.

Comment: Solution edited. Try it now.

Comment: I have more than 17,000 records in excel.... the solution is taking long time to calculate... still checking

Comment: Since i don't like it taking too long, i've written down a VBA solution that will most likely take less. Try it and send feedback.